# Declarative_Athorization: with_permissions_to for all models on single place

Tags: ruby-on-rails, finder, declarative-authorization

Is there a way to have with_permissions_to in a single place globally so that it applies to EVERY finder method of all models.

Actually, I have very big application and just added this plug-in for authorization. I don't want to use with_permissions_to with every find method for all models.

Thanks,
Imran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding:

```
default_scope { with_permissions_to(:read) }
```

to your models